# Сделал авто кликер, вчера работал идеально, сегодня просыпаюсь, решил потестить в приложениях, не работает

Tags: python

> python: can't open file 'C:\Users\Name\AU.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Код: `file:///C:/Users/777/Documents/Phytone/Games/SampGui/AU.py`

Comment: Не может найти файл когда пытаешься запустить скрипт

Comment: python C:/Users/777/Documents/Phytone/Games/SampGui/AU.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо, в момент запуска вы находитесь в каталоге `C:\Users\Name`, и Python ищет файл там.

Вам нужно перейти в каталог, в котором находится этот файл (`AU.py`), и выполнить команду `python AU.py`. Перейти в каталог можно командой `cd <ИМЯ КАТАЛОГА>`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, если баг не исправиться напишу ещё 1 вопрос

Comment: @Ms1, обновил ответ.